# How can I remove a variable number of lines from the top and bottom of multiple HTML documents?

Tags: html, regex, sed

I have a large number of html documents that need a variable number of lines removed from the top and bottom. The part I want always starts with `<div class="someclass">` and the bottom section always starts with `<div class="bottomouter>`. Something like this:

```
<html>
[...]
<div class="someclass"><!-- stuff i want to keep --></div>
<div class="bottomouter">[...]</div>
[...]
</html>
```

How could this be accomplished?

I'm working on a Linux box so I have access to Perl, Sed, Awk, &c. However, I don't know how to approach this (or if this is the right place to ask).

**Edit:** To clarify I'm moving a bunch of static document into a template system and they need the headers and footers removed.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client or on the server?

Comment: I'm moving a bunch of static document into a template system and they need the headers and footers removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a perl script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
$output_enabled = 1 if (/^<div class="someclass">/);
$output_enabled = 0 if (/^<div class="bottomouter">/);
print if ($output_enabled);
```

The `-n` option tells perl to apply the script to each line of input, putting the line in the `$_` variable (which is used implicitly in a lot of places in Perl; think of it like the word "it"). I set the `$output_enabled` variable (which persists across lines since it's a global variable, not declared with `my`) to `1` (true) if the current line matches the regex `/^<div class="someclass">/`, that is, if it starts with `<div class="someclass">`. Similarly, I set `$output_enabled` to `0` (false) if the line starts with `<div class="bottomouter">`. Finally, I print out the line if `$output_enabled` is true (it's initially false because it's undefined).

Comment: Not quite, the processing needs to happen once. (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What about this isn't happening once but needs to?

Comment: @indieinvader, see my edit for a description of how the script works.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/begPattern/,/endPattern/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

To output the part of the file between the delimiting lines without including them:

```
sed '1,/<div class="someclass">/d;/<div class="bottomouter">/,$d' inputfile
```